# Assign global role search

Tags: moodle

I've realized that by default, the search field in Assign global roles, only search users by name,surname and mail.

Is there a way to add a new field to search in? Ex: City, custom field, etc..

I tried to read source code and its OO puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

**Which version of Moodle do you have?**

Details below based on the [master](https://github.com/moodle/moodle) branch of moodle repository:

There are 2 classes that are used for searching for potential users:

- [core_role_potential_assignees_below_course](https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/admin/roles/classes/potential_assignees_below_course.php): for users within a course
- [core_role_potential_assignees_course_and_above](https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/admin/roles/classes/potential_assignees_course_and_above.php): for all users

In the global search `admin/roles/assign.php?contextid=1&roleid=2` the second class is used `core_role_potential_assignees_course_and_above`.

In the file [/admin/roles/assign.php](https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/admin/roles/assign.php#L94) line 94 the function `core_role_get_potential_user_selector` used to instantiate the object.

You can either modify the existing class or create a new class with your own implementations. (The second option is better in my opinion). If you created your own implemetation, then you will need to replace [line 94](https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/admin/roles/assign.php#L94).

In the class `core_role_potential_assignees_course_and_above` there is a method called `search_sql`. This method used to generate the "WHERE clause".

I hope this helps